# User agent stylesheet distorting site

Tags: users

I am creating my first wordpress site from its html version. My html site is quite simple and seems to be looking correct in popular browsers. You can see it now at k-gayduk.ru. In my every day life I use Mozilla so I used it in this work too. Everything was fine: my wp site was looking exactly as its html copy. However, when I checked other browsers I found that user agent stylesheet distorted it in Google Chrome and in IE8 to very high extent as well. This means that wp influenced css styles in this specific way. I googled the problem, but found nothing except reset.css suggestion which was useless in the case. However I think I am not the first one facing the problem. Appreciate any help on the matter. I should say sorry as not able to show wordpress site because it is still on localhost.

Comment: User Agent Stylesheets are browser specific meaning each browser has it's own default css that it uses for elements. As a web developer you have to compensate for these things sometimes. This is not WordPress specific.

Comment: I see your point Howdy_McGee, thank you. User agent stylesheet does not influence the html version, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a CSS reset to your css. I use [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) while developing WordPress themes.

Comment: The point is I did not use CSS reset in html version and everything was fine. What I am trying to find now is why default stylesheets distort site after moving from html to wp.

Comment: Might be a plugin that is adding unwanted styles. Or perhaps your theme is adding some styles you don't know about. Have you built it on a starter theme, or did you code it from scratch?

Comment: thank you for your help. I am building the theme from scratch. As for now I stopped looking for answers and again changing html-code to make it compatible with all browsers.